# Open the terminal in python and run a python script

Tags: python, terminal

How could I write a program that opens up the users terminal and runs a python script file? I've already looked around a bit, but all I can find is programs that open up the terminal to run a command, which is not what I want to do. I want to open up the terminal and run a python script file.

Comment: You can run a command to run a python script file. If you already have found programs that open the terminal to run a command, you can just replace the command with the command used to run the script.

Comment: Why don't you just write `python <script_name>` instead of the command?

Comment: @theharshest Would I put that in the script file, or in the command line?

Comment: @NotAGoodCoder I mean to say the same as aIKid's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to run a python script, you'll *have* to run a command. A command to run the script, that is.

You can just use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "userscript.py"])
```

Or the less preferred alternative, [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system("python userscript.py")
```

If you wonder why it's less preferred, here is a quote from the docs:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is __os.system__, the "less preferred" "alternative"?

Comment: Nothing much. It's just that the `subprocess` module have more features and it's better in handling processes. I'll update my answer.